# How do I download file on Mega since it does not work using urllib.urlretrieve?

Tags: python

When I try urllib.urlretrieve(url) is does not work as expected and returns nothing when I try it on [MEGA](https://www.mega.nz)
How could I :

- Download a file using python (windows)
- Upload a file using python (windows)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This library is deprecated since April 28, 2018, but if you only need download a file still works with python 2.7

You can install it with this command:

```
pip install mega.py
```

Here is an example:

```
from mega import Mega

mega = Mega()

m = mega.login()

m.download_url('https://mega.nz/#!EBZCXCjZ!tCUNt4nempTV9PQi4Rq6RFuDIU8t_87gXdFxJmmqFKo')
```

Also you can see the project on [Github](https://github.com/richardARPANET/mega.py).

Comment: It takes ages to download a small file.

Answer (score 0):

Mega is encrypted client-side, using js, so your only option might be to use a headless browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). or the [provided c++ sdk](https://mega.nz/#sdk)

Comment: But I'd like to do it using Python!
I saw something called Selenium, what advices could you give me?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this old question because it came up when I was looking for a solution.

The `mega` Python library is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py) because MEGA now has an official CLI.

You can install according to the instructions [there](https://mega.io/cmd#downloadapps) and then either use it directly in a terminal or in Python with `subprocess`. Something like:

```
import subprocess

url = "some file you want to download"
destfile = "path/to/save/file" #optional

subprocess.run(["mega-get", url, destfile])
```